# Link is opened as a path instead of url in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to code my portfolio in Ruby on Rails, and there is a problem when I want to set the link to my project.

Problem: I set the link like this `<a href="www.example.org"target="_blank">Visit <%= project.title %></a>`
and instead of displaying it in a new window like www.example.org it is displayed as http://localhost:3000/www.example.org.

Sorry if it is a dumb question but I am a newbie. Lots of thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `<a href="http://www.example.org" target="_blank">...</a>`

If you don't specify the scheme (e.g. http://) the browser will interpret the link as relative to the current domain.

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) and huge thanks for the explanation also.